# Insert image at specified position in webbrowser in C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to add an image at my cursor position in web-browser of C#, indeed I want a scenario where user clicks on button and image gets inserted at cursor position, which is inside web-browser, without affecting other text, is there any way to do it? So, I can paste image into specific cursor position, right now I am able to insert at last only. I also found [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/98fdb4d7-e0c3-4d15-8c20-727675fc97b7/how-to-get-caret-position-in-webbrowser-control)..

Comment: You need to look at css  absolute positioning.

Comment: thank you..but can you provide me link or example..and is it possible to give mouse cursor's x and y location as absolute position value..